# How to disable/hide/remove close(x)button of property page in MFC?

Tags: mfc

I am using a property sheet. The last page contains the Finish button which displays a successful registration message.

But if the user clicks the x button the (Finish) property page, the DoModal method returns ID_CANCEL meaning the registration was unsuccessful.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Ok  I got the answer for this.. In propertysheet class add the following code in InitDialog                       CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();                                    CMenu *pMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);                 pMenu->DeleteMenu(SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than remove the close button, you should trap the close button event inside the wizard dialog and at that point put up a *yes/no* message box asking the user *do they really want to cancel the wizard?*.

If the user answers yes then then just dismiss the wizard, but if the user answered no then cancel the event and the wizard will not be closed.

If you remove the close button you will be denying the user of a legitimate way of cancelling the wizard and I think that is a mistake.

Comment: This is last wizard, the user already paid money for s/w. if the user by mistake cancel window. He will lose the money.. So i did like that.

Answer (score 9):

In `OnInitDialog()` remove the `WS_SYSMENU` style (which will remove the close button):

```
ModifyStyle( WS_SYSMENU, 0 );
```

Comment: This also removes the application icon from the title bar (on my CFrameWnd class).